# Does Nightwing have a utility belt?

Tags: dc, nightwing

Does Nightwing use a utility belt?

In any comic books or does he always just wear his blue uniform without a utility belt?

Answer (score 5):

The original Nightwing did!  In the Pre-Crisis days of DC when Dick Grayson first became Nightwing, he acknowledged that Superman was a mentor second only to Batman and that the name came from Superman's Kryptonian heritage.

From "Superman" #158 (1963), Nightwing (and Flamebird) with ultility belts!

[image]

Comment: Fun fact: Nightwing carries a supply of batarang type projectiles that he calls 'wing dings'.

Comment: Is that not Jimmy there, as opposed to Dick?

Comment: Jimmy Olsen and Superman, check!  The original question asked about "Nightwing".  No mention of "Dick Grayson".  (I realize that was most  likely the intent of the question, but I thought this an interesting bit of comic lore)

Comment: Batman the conspiracy theorist with his tin foil hat.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the *version* of Nightwing we're speaking of. Most modern versions carry *some* form of Utility belt.....

[image: Young Justice version]
*Young justice* version

[image: _Titans_ version]

*Titans* version...

[image]

*Arkham Knight* version...

[image]

Various comic armor versions [ note the red lines].

These belts can take various forms, from military-like satchels, to small compartments weaved into his suit. They are usually a combination of stylistic choices melded with functionality; Dick always thought that Batman's versions of the belts were a bit "too heavy and limiting"; remember, unlike Bruce, who is stronger and more balanced, Dick's main skill has always been his quickness and *agility,* ... as such, he's always preferred his suits to be a bit more aerodynamic and flexible.

To be *fair,* though...there are several versions of the suits in which he keeps his gear not in *belts*, but in:

- boot pouches
- small side or back packs
- compartmentalized gauntlets [you can see examples in the first row of the comic versions.)

The DCAU version was designed this way specifically, to make him more distinct from the rest of the bat-family..

[image]

To be even *more* fair, he kind of picked this up from Batman; while the majority of the bat-gear is in the belt, he also has communications gear in the cowl, small blades or blowguns in his boots, detachable blades in his gauntlets, and even phalanges in some of his capes.

This would also be dependant on the **severity of the mission,** to a degree; in some comics, we see him "gearing up" and putting on a belt specifically because he's going to need certain things. So again, it varies...